# Knex not find the migrations path with esm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, es6-modules

I'm using knex in 0.21.5 and i was enable the esm module. Its creates normaly the migration (Using the command: yarn knex migrate: make * migration name * --esm) in directory path, but not execute them. Using the command knex migrate: list this appears even though i created the migration:

```
Using environment: development
FS-related option specified for migration configuration. This resets migrationSource to default FsMigrations
FS-related option specified for migration configuration. This resets migrationSource to default FsMigrations
No Completed Migration files Found. 
No Pending Migration files Found.

Done in 1.66s.
```

Config Knexfile:

```
import path from 'path';

export default {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection:
      'postgres:*link of database*',
    migrations: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, '/src/database/migrations/'),
      loadExtensions: ['mjs'],
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, in this case the load extensions ['mjs'] are not working, so I removed them and it worked, but you have to put the flag - esm in all the functions you did, so if you want to create a migration, for example, you need to run knex --esm migrate:make **name of migration**

Answer (score 0):

For me,

I have a combination of `Typescript` and `ESM`,

I got it run with this:
`node --loader ts-node/esm ./node_modules/.bin/knex migrate:latest`

Reference: [Knex issue](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/4793#issuecomment-1136127506)